# how to merger wizrocket events from app and web?

Tags: android, events, web-applications

I have added wizrocket sdk in my applicatoin and inside the application i am opening webapp which also has wizrocket integration, now my app sends events and webapp also but wizrocket identifies both event for different user. how to combine both events ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by passing a common identity value when those events are being raised.  It can be the user’s email id, a phone number or any other identifier that you are using to tag your users.This is the key that will be looked up to find the user whose profile needs to be updated. If this identity is not found a new user profile will be created.

Comment: i can't do so, as i want to create a funnel where user first opens app and then do X activity and then Y , the problem here is app launched event is sent from mobile and then X and Y event is sent from site, so in wizrocket it shows both as different user, also in that activity I dont have any email id or mobile number to pass.

Answer (score 0):

Kalpit - can you not pass the user's mobile number from the app to the web view? If you do so, and set it as an Identity then it'll go to the same user profile.

Comment: i Know that if i pass the value it will match the profile and then it will show same profile together , but I can not pass the mobile number or mail id.